# Chamar um relatório com sub-relatório a partir de uma Managedbean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee, jasper-reports

Alguém tem um exemplo em Java de como chamar a partir de uma Managedbean um relatório com sub-relatório?

Eu já tenho o relatório com o sub-relatório a funcionar bem no ireport,mas quando tento chamar a partir da aplicação ele chama apenas o relatório principal.
P.s. estou a trabalhar de forma separada, ou seja, desenvolvo os relatórios no ireport e depois chamo a partir de uma MB

Comment: Posta os códigos para que possamos lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: O sub relatório esta configurado e com os dados ligados à fonte de dados bean?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflowPt, por favor inclua o trecho do seu código, erro ou tentativa na sua pergunta, dessa forma fica mais fácil de a comunidade ajudá-lo com seu problema.